# SharePoint 2010 Calendar overlay feed from Exchange problems

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calendar

So SharePoint 2010 has this handy new calendar overlays feature which allows you to render up 10 other calendars inside of one master SharePoint calendar. There is an option to pull from Exchange calendar as well. The only parameters it provides is the OWA url and the OWA web service url.

We use Exchange online and it isn't working whatsoever. I don't see any fields that store the credential information to connect to Exchange anywhere, and we get back a message saying that there is no email address configured in the profile (there really is). Documentation on the web is sparse for this. My questions are:

1. Is there a place where I can set credentials for this connection (if so where)?
2. Can I have it link to shared group calendars in Exchange not just an individuals calendar?
3. Will this work with MS hosted Exchange online?

Answer (score 0):

I eliminated the "no email address configured" message by adding my exchange email to my SharePoint user profile.

It should pass the current user's credentials (used to connect to SharePoint) through the source services.

So far, I've been unable to connect to shared calendars in Exchange successfully.